# Modifing RSS nodes in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have been asked by my work to add a `rel='nofollow'` to the WordPress RSS feed on our site. Now the RSS feed **already** has the `rel='nofollow'` added to all the `<a href>` tags which is working fine. What they are really asking is to add the `nofollow` to the actual RSS `node` itself.

They basically want `<link rel='nofollow'>` instead of `<link>`

Would adding a `nofollow` at the node level actually do anything? I understand it working at the `href` level but it seems odd to do this here. If this does work as expected then using PHP how can I modify this node to add this namespace?

Here is an example of my RSS feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
        xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title>Article Title here</title>
    <link>http://fakewebsiteurl.com</link>
    <description>article description here</description>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <generator>https://wordpress.org/?v=4.5.2</generator>
    <item>
        <title>Test Article</title>
        <link>http://fakewebsiteurl.com/news/test-article/</link>
        <comments>http://fakewebsiteurl.com/news/test-article/#respond</comments>
        <pubDate>Thu, 05 May 2016 18:16:50 +0000</pubDate>

        <description><![CDATA[<p>Description text here</p>
<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="fakewebsiteurl.com/news/test-article/">Test Article</a> appeared here</p>
]]></description>
    </item>
    <item>
        ...
    </item>
</channel>
```

I have a custom PHP page that modifies this RSS already but I am not sure if I need to replace the node completely or if there is a away to modify it directly. I was thinking of using `str_replace` but that did not work.

```
<?php

namespace X;

class RssFeed {

    public function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'the_content_feed', array( $this, 'add_nofollow_href' ) );
    }

    function add_nofollow_namespace($content) {
        if (is_feed()) {
            $link = '<link>';
            $linkno = '<link rel="nofollow">';
            $updated = str_replace($link, $linkno, $content);
            return $updated;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance. Code examples appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the [W3C Feed Validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) with the `rel="nofollow"` attribute on the `<link>` tag:

> This feed does not validate. line 13, column 1: Unexpected rel
>   attribute on link element [help] 
>   `<link rel="nofollow">http://exapmle.tld</link>`

so the modified feed would not [validate](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-nofollow):

> The `nofollow` keyword may be used with a and area elements. This
>   keyword does not create a hyperlink, but annotates any other
>   hyperlinks created by the element (the implied hyperlink, if no other
>   keywords create one).
>
> The `nofollow` keyword indicates that the link is not endorsed by the
>   original author or publisher of the page, or that the link to the
>   referenced document was included primarily because of a commercial
>   relationship between people affiliated with the two pages.

The `<link>` tag is [required](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#requiredChannelElements) by the rss2 specification, so removing (via plugin or custom template) wouldn't be an option. A drastic approach would be to disable the whole feed altogether (e.g. mentioned [here](https://yoast.com/rss-feeds-panda-penguin/)).

It's possible to add a custom *namsespace* via the `rss2_ns` hook and custom channel nodes via the `rss2_head` hook. The *atom* namespace is already included for the *self* relationship of:

```
<atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

Out of curiosity I tested:

```
<atom:link href="<?php bloginfo_rss('url'); ?>" 
           rel="nofollow" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

This gave a valid feed, but with warnings regarding `nofollow` as an unregistered [link relationship](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/UnregisteredAtomLinkRel.html). But I'm not sure if the search bots would consider this kind of approach?

**Previous answer:**

Appart from creating a custom feed template (as mentioned by @mevius), the only workaround I can think of is the following *output buffering* hack through the `rss_tag_pre` and `rss2_head` hooks:

```
add_action( 'rss_tag_pre', function( $tag )
{
    if( 'rss2' === $tag )
        ob_start();
} );

add_action( 'rss2_head', function()
{       
    echo str_replace( '<link>', '<link rel="nofollow">',  ob_get_clean() );
} );
```

where we target the *rss2* feed template.

If you think it's worth to have such an attribute, then you can always create a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to reliably do this will be to [create a custom feed template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds#Customizing_Feed_Templates). As you can see from [the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/703d5bdc8deb17781e9c6d8f0dd7e2c6b6353885/wp-includes/feed-rss.php), the `<link>` in the core feed templates is hard-coded as the following:

```
<link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
```

There is no way to edit attributes of this tag via a filter.